# Как сделать так чтоб ф-я работала только при активном чекбоксе?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть чек бокс, который указывает юр. или физ. лицо

```
<input type="checkbox" name="phisic" id="phisic" />
```

Еще есть функция которая копирует текст из одного поля в другой.

```
$(function () {
    var $src = $('#company-name-input'),
        $dst = $('#customer-name-input');
        $src.on('input', function () {
        $dst.val($src.val());
    });    
});
```

Как сделать так чтобы она работала только если чекбокс активен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="company-name-input">
<input type="text" id="customer-name-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="phisic" id="phisic" />

$(function () {
    var $src = $('#company-name-input'),
        $dst = $('#customer-name-input'),
        $checkbox = $('#phisic'); //вводим переменную для чекбокса
        $src.on('input', function () {
        if ($checkbox.prop("checked")) { // используем метод prop(), который вернёт true, если чекбокс имеет атрибут checked
            $dst.val($src.val());
        }
    });    
});
```

Работающий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/4um9xgze/

Answer (score 0):

Простите. Много вариантов перепробовал и не работало. Как тему создал получилось.

```
$(function () {
    var $src = $('#company-name-input'),
        $dst = $('#customer-name-input');
        $src.on('input', function () {
        if ($('#phisic').is(':checked')) {
        $dst.val($src.val());
    }
    });    
});
```